# Appengine search index and namespaces

Tags: google-app-engine, go, namespaces

I am writing a multi-tenant application using appengine namespaces. We need a separate index per tenant for searching employees (to avoid the 10GB limit of a search index).

If I create a search index "employees" (in golang **search.Open("employees")** ) and index the following docs (using golang api **search.Put(ctx, id, doc)** )

1. doc1 from tenant 1 with namespace "abc" and
2. doc2 from tenant 2 with namespace "xyz"

do these docs go into a single index or two different indexes in two different namespaces? I want to make sure that I am not hitting the 10GB limit.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on NAMESPACE the data divides.
if "employees" has one namespace it will store under its namespace.
if we provide another NAMESPACE the data will store in that namespace only.

i think u r asking the same thing.